# GET url in search and sort logic

Tags: django, url, search

I have this url after you hit the search button:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/results/?name=blab&city=bla&km=12
```

my view:

```
def search(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    km = request.GET.get('km')

    if name!="" and name != None: 
        locations = Location.objects.filter(name__istartswith=name)
        return render_to_response("result-page.html",{'locations':locations},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    if city!="" and city != None: 
         locations = Location.objects.filter(city__istartswith=city)
         return render_to_response("result-page.html",{'locations':locations},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but now, if i look for both name and city, it is giving ony the results search after name. e.g. the first paramater. second one is not being taken.

what is the best logic for this? i also want to able to sort the search result. can you please give me some hints how to this kind of things in clean logic.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning on the first if, if you want to filter on either or both or no parameters try using one QuerySet with dynamic filters e.g. something like

```
search_kwargs = {}

if request.GET.get('name'):
    search_kwargs['name__istartswith'] = request.GET.get('name')

if request.GET.get('city'):
    search_kwargs['city__istartswith'] = request.GET.get('city')

locations = Location.objects.filter(**search_kwargs)

return render_to_response("result-page.html",{'locations':locations},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

or even something like

```
filter_fields = ['city','name']
for f in filter_fields:
    if f in request.GET:
        search_kwargs['%s__istartswith' % f] = request.GET.get(f)
```

Comment: fantastic! what does ``**`` do?

Comment: Yes you could add as many filters (of any type - icontains,equals etc) as you want to search_kwargs, if that's what you mean?

Comment: but i have this query: ``Location.objects.filter(locations_rate__rate=int_bew).distinct('id')``
how can i put this into dict?